# JMeter - list of installed plugins

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I am using JMeter 5.2, only via Command Line Mode.

For debugging purposes I need to get a list of all currently installed plugins for the JMeter version.

How I could achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use plugin manager using [CLI](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManagerAutomated/):

> command-line is simple:
>
> ```
> PluginsManagerCMD <command> [<params>]
> ```

In your case execute status

```
PluginsManagerCMD status
```